# For Loop to compile data from multiple dataframes with varied number of observations

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, merge

I have created a `forloop` that iterates over a list of dataframes and creates a dataframe output like the one below. However, each possible pair of users does not appear in each dataframe; users appearance varies from one iteration to the next. Some dataframes only have 10 pairs, while others have 200.

| user1 | user2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Scott | Clark | .067 |
| David | Sarah | .234 |
| David | Clark | .544 |
| Thomas | Sarah | .324 |
| Clark | Thomas | .761 |
| Sarah | Clark | .921 |

I would like to compile a single dataframe to hold the results (i.e. `value`) of each iteration, so the first two columns are used as a matching reference, and the value column is added for each iteration, populating the cells with the values matching the two users. Each value column being identifiable by the date represented as `i` in each iteration (i = "2020"). However, some pairs of users may not have comparable data for a given iteration, in which case, I would like those cells to have NA. The resulting dataframe should look something like the one below.

| user1 | user2 | value_2018 | value_2019 | value_2020 | value_2021 | value_2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Scott | Clark | .067 | .067 | .098 | .067 | .098 |
| David | Sarah | .234 | NA | .777 | .222 | .756 |
| David | Clark | .544 | .567 | .754 | .121 | .334 |
| Thomas | Sarah | .324 | .123 | NA | NA | .443 |
| Scott | Clark | .761 | .234 | .437 | .878 | .543 |
| David | Sarah | .921 | .345 | .958 | NA | .299 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I am failing to include some important information.

Here is the dput info:

```
structure(list(user1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Bilirakis_Gus", "Boozman_John", "Brady_Kevin", 
"Buchanan_Vern", "Burgess_Michael", "Burr_Richard", "Carter_John", 
"Chabot_Steve", "Collins_Susan", "Cornyn_John", "Fortenberry_Jeff", 
"Foxx_Virginia", "Grassley_Charles", "Graves_Sam", "Jordan_Jim", 
"Latta_Robert", "Lummis_Cynthia", "McCarthy_Kevin", "McCaul_Michael", 
"McClintock_Tom", "McHenry_Patrick", "Murkowski_Lisa", "Portman_Robert", 
"Posey_Bill", "Rodgers_Cathy", "Rogers_Mike", "Thompson_Glenn", 
"Thune_John", "Toomey_Patrick", "Wicker_Roger", "Wilson_Joe"), class = "factor"), 
    user2 = structure(1:10, .Label = c("Boozman_John", "Brady_Kevin", 
    "Buchanan_Vern", "Burgess_Michael", "Burr_Richard", "Carter_John", 
    "Chabot_Steve", "Collins_Susan", "Cornyn_John", "Fortenberry_Jeff", 
    "Foxx_Virginia", "Grassley_Charles", "Graves_Sam", "Jordan_Jim", 
    "Latta_Robert", "Lummis_Cynthia", "McCarthy_Kevin", "McCaul_Michael", 
    "McClintock_Tom", "McHenry_Patrick", "Murkowski_Lisa", "Portman_Robert", 
    "Posey_Bill", "Rodgers_Cathy", "Rogers_Mike", "Thompson_Glenn", 
    "Thune_John", "Toomey_Patrick", "Wicker_Roger", "Wilson_Joe", 
    "Wittman_Robert"), class = "factor"), rhetsim = c(0.532304260552694, 
    0.565448793804611, 0.614746610378663, 0.41456827871494, 0.680331655545798, 
    0.402937226093047, 0.635434336603617, 0.703608799728453, 
    0.592589001800602, 0.561932070884369)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Okay, I just added a dput of a subset of the data.

Comment: If you're looping over a list of data.frames, and you find users with "non-comparable data", then assign a value of NA to that entry? I'm not sure what the issue is without knowing what operations you're performing in the loop. Also the supplied data is a 10x3 frame for me.